# Render page based on IP location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a site built with Ruby on Rails (RefineryCMS). Nginx is the server. Using Phusion Passenger.

How can I direct the site to render pages based on the user's IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the nginx [geo](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoModule) module.

There's a very similar question and answer here:

[Use Nginx to server different pages depending on IP address/subnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/267611/use-nginx-to-server-different-pages-depending-on-ip-address-subnet)

Comment: Will the geo module identify a users city and redirect based on that city? Does this cost money?